# How can I align two tables up and down?

Tags: tables, minipage, two-column, alignment

I have two tables, and I want to put them in the same row in a two-column mode. But when I use the code below, none of them are aligned, and a table cannot be displayed completely. What should I do? Thank you!

[image]

```
   \begin{table*}[t]
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth}
            \begin{center}
                \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|}
                    \hline
                    data load nums  & W        & L       \\ \hline
                    p1 (k/ms) & $3.000*10^8$  &$3.000*10^8$  \\ \hline
                    p2 (k/ms)  &$3.000*10^8$  & $3.000*10^8$   \\ \hline
                    p3 (k/ms) & $3.000*10^8$ & $3.000*10^8$ \\ \hline
                    Total (k/ms) & $3.000*10^8$  &$3.000*10^8$  \\ \hline
                \end{tabular}
                \caption{Process.}
                \label{table:formatting}
            \end{center}
        \end{minipage}\hfill
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\linewidth}
            \begin{center}
                \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
                    \hline
                    & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}p1 TB\\ Alg.1\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}sender \& pcc \\ Alg.1\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}sender only \\ Alg.1\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}p2 TB\\ Alg.2\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}sender \& pcc \\ Alg.2\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}sender only \\ Alg.2\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
                    \textbf{L1D} & 0.041\%                                                        & 0.111\%                                                                 & 0.111\%                                                             & 0.111\%                                                     & 0.111\%                                                            & 0.111\%                                                      \\ \hline
                    \textbf{L2}  & 3.586\%                                                        & 0.111\%                                                       & 0.111\%                                                        & 0.111\%                                               & 0.111\%                                                           & 0.111\%                                                     \\ \hline
                    \textbf{LLC} & 34.379\%                                                       & 0.111\%                                                          & 0.111\%                                                        & 0.111\%                                           & 0.111\%                                                             & 0.111\%                                                      \\ \hline
                \end{tabular}
                \caption{ Algorithm 1.}
                \label{table:formatting}
            \end{center}
        \end{minipage}%
    \end{table*}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant packages. See also: [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) The right table is running onto the margin since it is wider than the 0.6\textwidth wide minipage you placed it inside of.

Comment: You can make your tables narrower by placing repeated information such as units in the column headers and by allowing more linebreaks in the column headers. [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/134144) contains some more useful tricks in order to make sure a table fits into the available space.

Answer (score 1):

Since documentclass, margins and font sizes are unknow, the following three suggestions are based on assumptions:

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{lipsum} % Just for dummy text. Do not use in actual document.
\begin{document}
\lipsum



\begin{table*}
\centering
                \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
                    \hline
                    & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}p1 TB\\ Alg.1\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}sender \& pcc \\ Alg.1\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}sender only \\ Alg.1\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}p2 TB\\ Alg.2\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}sender \& pcc \\ Alg.2\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}sender only \\ Alg.2\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
                    \textbf{L1D} & 0.041\%                                                        & 0.111\%                                                                 & 0.111\%                                                             & 0.111\%                                                     & 0.111\%                                                            & 0.111\%                                                      \\ \hline
                    \textbf{L2}  & 3.586\%                                                        & 0.111\%                                                       & 0.111\%                                                        & 0.111\%                                               & 0.111\%                                                           & 0.111\%                                                     \\ \hline
                    \textbf{LLC} & 34.379\%                                                       & 0.111\%                                                          & 0.111\%                                                        & 0.111\%                                           & 0.111\%                                                             & 0.111\%                                                      \\ \hline
                \end{tabular}
                \caption{ Algorithm 1.}
                \label{table:formatting}
\end{table*} 

\begin{table}
\centering
                \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|}
                    \hline
                    data load nums  & W        & L       \\ \hline
                    p1 (k/ms) & $3.000*10^8$  &$3.000*10^8$  \\ \hline
                    p2 (k/ms)  &$3.000*10^8$  & $3.000*10^8$   \\ \hline
                    p3 (k/ms) & $3.000*10^8$ & $3.000*10^8$ \\ \hline
                    Total (k/ms) & $3.000*10^8$  &$3.000*10^8$  \\ \hline
                \end{tabular}
                \caption{Process.}
                \label{table:formatting}
\end{table}

\lipsum

\begin{table*}[t]
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.35\linewidth}
            \centering
            \caption{Process.}
            \label{table:formatting}
                \begin{tabular}[t]{c*{2}{S[table-format=1.2]}}
                    \toprule
                    \thead{data load\\ nums\\ (\si{k\per\milli\second})}  & {\thead{W $\cdot 10^8$}}       & {\thead{L $\cdot 10^8$}}       \\ \midrule
                    p1    & 3.00 & 3.00 \\ 
                    p2    & 3.00 & 3.00 \\ 
                    p3    & 3.00 & 3.00 \\ 
                    Total & 3.00 & 3.00 \\ \bottomrule
                \end{tabular}
        \end{minipage}\hfill
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.65\linewidth}
            \centering
            \caption{ Algorithm 1.}
            \label{table:formatting}
                \begin{tabular}[t]{lS[table-format=2.3]*{5}{S[table-format=1.3]}}
                    \toprule
                    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Alg.1} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Alg.2}\\
                    \cmidrule(r){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7}
                    & {\thead{p1 TB\\ (\%)}} 
                      & {\thead{sender \\ \& pcc  (\%)}} 
                        & {\thead{sender \\ only  (\%)}}  
                          & {\thead{p1 TB\\ (\%)}} 
                            & {\thead{sender \\ \& pcc  (\%)}} 
                              & {\thead{sender \\ only  (\%)}}\\
                   \midrule
                    L1D & 0.041  & 0.111 & 0.111 & 0.111 & 0.111 & 0.111 \\ 
                    L2  & 3.586  & 0.111 & 0.111 & 0.111 & 0.111 & 0.111 \\ 
                    LLC & 34.379 & 0.111 & 0.111 & 0.111 & 0.111 & 0.111 \\ 
                    \bottomrule
                \end{tabular}
        \end{minipage}%
    \end{table*}
    
    \lipsum
    \lipsum 
    
    
\begin{table*}
            \centering
            \caption{ Algorithm 1.}
            \label{table:formatting}
                \begin{tabular}[t]{lS[table-format=2.3]*{5}{S[table-format=1.3]}}
                    \toprule
                    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Alg.1} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Alg.2}\\
                    \cmidrule(r){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7}
                    & {\thead{p1 TB (\%)}} 
                      & {\thead{sender  \& pcc  (\%)}} 
                        & {\thead{sender  only  (\%)}}  
                          & {\thead{p1 TB (\%)}} 
                            & {\thead{sender  \& pcc  (\%)}} 
                              & {\thead{sender  only  (\%)}}\\
                   \midrule
                    L1D & 0.041  & 0.111 & 0.111 & 0.111 & 0.111 & 0.111 \\ 
                    L2  & 3.586  & 0.111 & 0.111 & 0.111 & 0.111 & 0.111 \\ 
                    LLC & 34.379 & 0.111 & 0.111 & 0.111 & 0.111 & 0.111 \\ 
                    \bottomrule
                \end{tabular}
\end{table*} 

\begin{table}
\centering
                \caption{Process.}
                \label{table:formatting}
                \begin{tabular}[t]{c*{2}{S[table-format=1.2]}}
                    \toprule
                    \thead{data load nums\\ (\si{k\per\milli\second})}  & {\thead{W $\cdot 10^8$}}       & {\thead{L $\cdot 10^8$}}       \\ \midrule
                    p1    & 3.00 & 3.00 \\ 
                    p2    & 3.00 & 3.00 \\ 
                    p3    & 3.00 & 3.00 \\ 
                    Total & 3.00 & 3.00 \\ \bottomrule
                \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A possibility with `floatrow` and `makecell`(and `caption` to have a decent spacing between caption and table):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\small\bfseries}
\usepackage[valign=t,heightadjust=all]{floatrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
    \begin{floatrow}[2]
      \ttabbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{Process.}%
                \label{table:formatting}
        }{ \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|}
                    \hline
                    \makecell{data load\\ nums} & W & L \\ \hline
                    \makecell{p1\\ (k/ms)} & $3.000*10^8$ &$3.000*10^8$ \\ \hline
                    \makecell{p2\\ (k/ms)} &$3.000*10^8$ & $3.000*10^8$ \\ \hline
                    \makecell{p3 \\(k/ms)} & $3.000*10^8$ & $3.000*10^8$ \\ \hline
                    \makecell{Total \\(k/ms)} & $3.000*10^8$ &$3.000*10^8$ \\ \hline
                \end{tabular}}
      \ttabbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{ Algorithm 1.}
                \label{table:formatting1}}%
        {\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
                    \hline
                    & \thead{p1 TB\\ Alg.1 \\(\%)} & \thead{sender\\ \& pcc \\ Alg.1 \\(\%)} & \thead{sender\\ only \\ Alg.1\\ (\%)} & \thead{p2 TB\\ Alg.2\\ (\%)} & \thead{sender \\\& pcc \\ Alg.2\\ (\%)} & \thead{sender\\ only \\ Alg.2\\ (\%)} \\ \hline
                    \thead{L1D} & 0.041 & 0.111 & 0.111 & 0.111 & 0.111 & 0.111 \\ \hline
                    \thead{L2} & 3.586 & 0.111 & 0.111 & 0.111 & 0.111 & 0.111 \\ \hline
                    \thead{LLC} & 34.379 & 0.111 & 0.111 & 0.111 & 0.111 & 0.111 \\ \hline
                \end{tabular}}
    \end{floatrow}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]